# I need an app that can automatically creates a subtitle files (usually srt) from movies

Tags: video

Are there such apps?

Video are often a few gigabytes. So webapp is not a good match.

I need an app, paid or free, that will open video files and create subtitles.

Comment: From the movies alone? Like in speech-to-text conversion?

Comment: Yes. Precisely. So I don't need to find subtitles from subtitles.com and stuff

Comment: Doing so is certainly possible, but generally meet with terrible results. Youtube, for example, has such feature (automatically generated subtitles) and the resulting text is..... less than perfect to be generous. You'll be better off searching for subtitles or creating them yourself than letting a computer make them.

Comment: Speech detection with multiple speakers and a lot of audio effects like in movies is not yet usable. There are some projects aiming in automatic subtitle generation via speech-to-text for lectures with a limited number of speakers and a relative quite environment.